# How to block hasRole in spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have an Spring MVC java site that uses Spring Security  to restrict user access.
Example :

```
<security:authorize access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_EMPLOYEE', 'ROLE_MANAGER')">
    ...
</security:authorize>
```

Now how can I block access ROLE_MANAGER and allow all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put `!hasAnyRole` instead of `hasAnyRole`, It's help to block access `ROLE_MANAGER` and allow all.

```
<security:authorize access="!hasAnyRole('ROLE_MANAGER')">
    ...
</security:authorize>
```